# Publishing frequently changing iCalendar via METHOD:PUBLISH in combination with SEQUENCE

Tags: icalendar

I am using the [ical-generator](https://github.com/sebbo2002/ical-generator) library to publish an iCalendar feed. The calendar contains an all-day event, which is a prediction of something happening on a given day. As the prediction gets updated, I want to change the date of the event accordingly.

This is how the feed looks like for an example event on 21 Feb 2021:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//sebbo.net//ical-generator//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
TIMEZONE-ID:Europe/Berlin
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:42
SEQUENCE:26852582
DTSTAMP:20210120T150245Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210121
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-MSNCALENDAR-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
SUMMARY:Test
ORGANIZER;CN="XXX":mailto:xxx@xxx.com
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1M
LAST-MODIFIED:20210120T150245Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I want to update the event, I am using the same `UID` but update `DTSTART` and `SEQUENCE` (I am using "minutes since epoch" to be really sure that my sequence numbers are properly reflecting update order).

Now suppose that the prediction changes, and the event must be moved to the next day:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//sebbo.net//ical-generator//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
TIMEZONE-ID:Europe/Berlin
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:42
SEQUENCE:26852583
DTSTAMP:20210120T150309Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210122
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
X-MICROSOFT-MSNCALENDAR-ALLDAYEVENT:TRUE
SUMMARY:Test
ORGANIZER;CN="XXX":mailto:xxx@xxx.com
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1M
LAST-MODIFIED:20210120T150309Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Note:

- `UID` is the same
- `DTSTART` is now 22 Feb 2021
- `SEQUENCE` is incremented by 1 (minute)

All major clients (Outlook Web Acccess, Google Calendar, Apple Calendar) properly display the feed, but they **don't reflect any updates** to the event.

What am I missing?

Comment: Has SEQUENCE really been updated 26852583 times ? (why the 'minute' behind it? )  See https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-7-4-sequence-number.html

Comment: Are you updating LAST-MODIFIED too?   Some applications use that too.

Comment: The UID is supposed to be a persistent, GLOBALLY unique identifier.   42 while it may have lots of hidden meaning is unlikely to be globally unique? Usually some part of the originating website or email is included to make it unique.  See example given https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-4-7-unique-identifier.html

Comment: There may also be a delay in updates showing up - the receiving applications check for updates at their own pace.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @anmari!

I'm updating the calendar from a stateless function, so I'm using the 'minutes since epoch' to guarantee that SEQUENCE is incremented for each update. Afaik, the spec doesn't require SEQUENCE to start at 0 nor to be updated in increments of 1.

UID being 42 is just an example, but thanks for the reminder that it must be *globally* unique.

I actually think that everything is working as expected, but – just as you point out – receiving applications check at their own pace (less frequently than I would have hoped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that everything is working as expected, but – just as @anmari pointed out in a comment – receiving applications check at their own pace.

Comment: Such a helpful Q&A. For anyone else, one note is that the reason to use "minutes since epoch" for the SEQUENCE is because it is a 32-bit integer and can't hold milliseconds since epoch.